# Using li:hover is not showing div when the list item is an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm having an issue with my drop down menu. I am trying to have the end result look similar to BestBuy.com's navigation. The code is below along with more explanation at the end.

```
<div class="navbar">
<ul>
    <li>Products
        <div class="secondlevel">
            <ul>
                <li>Testing 1
                    <div class="thirdlevel two-columns">
                        <div class="column">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Testing 1</li>
                                <li>Testing 2</li>
                                <li>Testing 3</li>
                                <li>Testing 4</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Testing 1</li>
                                <li>Testing 2</li>
                                <li>Testing 3</li>
                                <li>Testing 4</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>Testing 2
                    <div class="thirdlevel">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Testing 1</li>
                            <li>Testing 2</li>
                            <li>Testing 3</li>
                            <li>Testing 4</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>Testing 3</li>
                <li>Testing 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>Test Link</li>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
body {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    background: #eee;
}

.navbar {
    background:lightblue;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
}

.navbar ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.navbar ul>li {
    display:inline-block;
}

.navbar ul li ul>li {
    display:block;
}

.secondlevel {
    position:absolute;
    width:350px;
    height:477px;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0;
    border: 1px solid #c3c4c4;
}

.thirdlevel {
    position:absolute;
    width:350px;
    height:477px;
    background:lightgreen;
    left:350px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c4c4;
    top:-1px;
}

.thirdlevel.two-columns {
    width:700px;
}

.thirdlevel div:first-child {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}

.thirdlevel div {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}

.column {
    width:350px;
}

.thirdlevel {
    display:none;
}

.secondlevel {
    display:none;
}


.navbar li:hover > div:first-child {
    display:block;
}

.active {
    display:block;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I try to turn the list items into links with: `<li><a>Products</a><li>`

When I do that, hovering over the element no longer works.

Also, the hover effect doesn't work in IE either. I'm guessing that's because I'm using `li:hover`.

I was attempting to use jQuery for the hover effect, and I would really like to since I've read that it's better for what I need to do, but my knowledge is limited in that department.

From what I researched I could use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main-nav-item").hover(function () {
        $(".secondary-menu").toggleClass("active");
        $(".tertiary-menu").toggleClass("hide");
    });
});
```

Of course those classes don't line up with what I have, but that's the gist of what it is. The problem I had with that was I couldn't get it to work on only one child. Hopefully that's the right word. For example: When I hovered over my first `<li>` it would open all of the submenus. The way it is right now is perfect, except for the fact that nothing can be a link, which is kind of important.

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 1):

Try Making the links in the `<li><a>Link</a></li>` in to block Elements

```
a { display:block; }
```

did the trick for me

EDIT (Went Through you Problem)

Does this what you are asking for ..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".main-nav-item a").hover(function() {
    $(".secondlevel").addClass("active");
    $(".thirdlevel").addClass("hide");
  });

  $(".secondlevel").hover(function() {
    $(".thirdlevel").addClass("active");
  });


});
```

```css
body {

  font-family: sans-serif;

  background: #eee;

}

.navbar {

  background: #FFE;

  width: 100%;

  padding: 0;

}

.navbar ul {

  list-style: none;

  padding: 0;

  margin: 0;

}

.navbar ul>li {

  display: inline-block;

}

.navbar ul li ul>li {

  display: block;

}

.secondlevel {

  position: absolute;

  width: 350px;

  height: 477px;

  background: #fff;

  padding: 0;

  border: 1px solid #c3c4c4;

}

.thirdlevel {

  position: absolute;

  width: 350px;

  height: 477px;

  background: #AABC34;

  left: 350px;

  border: 1px solid #c3c4c4;

  top: -1px;

}

.thirdlevel.two-columns {

  width: 700px;

}

.thirdlevel div:first-child {

  position: absolute;

  left: 0;

}

.thirdlevel div {

  position: absolute;

  right: 0;

}

.column {

  width: 350px;

}

.thirdlevel {

  display: none;

}

.secondlevel {

  display: none;

}

.navbar li:hover > div:first-child {

  display: block;

}

.active {

  display: block;

}

a {

  display: block;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li class="main-nav-item">
      <a href="#">Products</a>
      <div class="secondlevel">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Testing 1</a>
            <div class="thirdlevel two-columns">
              <div class="column">
                <ul>
                  <li>Testing 1
                  </li>
                  <li>Testing 2
                  </li>
                  <li>Testing 3
                  </li>
                  <li>Testing 4
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <ul>
                  <li>Testing 1
                  </li>
                  <li>Testing 2
                  </li>
                  <li>Testing 3
                  </li>
                  <li>Testing 4
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>Testing 2
            <div class="thirdlevel">
              <ul>
                <li>Testing 1
                </li>
                <li>Testing 2
                </li>
                <li>Testing 3
                </li>
                <li>Testing 4
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>Testing 3
          </li>
          <li>Testing 4
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>Test Link
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. here's a link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=bLGQNBvhji

Comment: Check out the Edit .. it was the block element... anchors don't inherit properties naturally though

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried `<a href=""><li>EXAMPLE</li></a>`? As for the IE side of things, I would recommend using IE specific styling or if you haven't already, used CSS Reset, for a start. Do you have a working example?

Comment: I tried that and It wouldn't work quite well, because the <li> includes the entire nav menu.

Comment: Ah I see. Didn't think of this, but I agree with @fuzail-lcorder making the hyperlink a display:block. Try that!